# Fillo Jar and Apache Poi

Tags: apache-poi

Is there a way to use both Fillo and Apache Poi in a single application.
My Fillo version 1.21
Apache Poi version 3.16

Without Apache poi Fillo works fine but when we include the Apache poi jars Fillo don't work. There is some sort of compatibility issue i guess. 
Is there any solution for the above issue.

Comment: What version of Apache POI does your chosen version of Fillo bundle?

Comment: "don't work" isn't quite helpful. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This involves more details on steps to reproduce, especially concrete error messages.

Comment: @Gagravarr don't have any idea regarding which version of Apache poi used in Fillo version 1.21

Comment: hi @OlafKock when ever i use Fillo jar along with poi jar i.e fillo jar for using the excel sheet as database and poi for read/write excel files. I get the error as below

Comment: 'Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
at com.codoid.products.fillo.CommonExcelUtil.getColumnNames(CommonExcelUtil.java:86)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.SelectExcelUtil.runSelectQuery(SelectExcelUtil.java:84)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Select.getRecordset(Select.java:61)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection.executeQuery(Connection.java:64)
at com.neo.suiteCreater.XLSReader.getTests(XLSReader.java:25)
at com.neo.suiteCreater.createSuite.main(createSuite.java:7)'

Comment: Try the [code in the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) to see what jar fillo embeds for POI?

Comment: @kichuf1 if you edit your question with this information, it won't get folded into the comments, can be formatted and makes a more complete question

Comment: For me filo and poi weren’t working together as well. When I tried to run a filly code it used to result as errors. 
Then in my Pom.XML I added filo first and then poi dependencies and both work